# How to Correctly Use `.grid()` with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following script and the following GUI.

Question(s):

1. How can I vertically center the 4 boxes on the left side? (There is extra space at the bottom).

   - I currently have grid with rows and columns which I thought would default vertically center, but that seems to not be the case. Or I did it wrong?
2. Within `mid`, I have 2 `frame`s that contain a series of buttons. I tried to place one of the frames above the buttons using the `grid(row=)` but that doesn't move the frame at all. I expected the behavior of the `left` view that contains the boxes but it didn't work out. **How can I get one frame of boxes above the other?**

Note: I'm sure there are simple solutions, I'm just missing it.

Note: I know I could use iteration for most of this, but I was looking to build up my tkinter skills hard-coding and then re-develop with more advanced topics.

**Tkinter Script.txt**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

#####################################################################################################
# UI

# Main Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('700x800')

## 3 Frames
left = tk.Frame(master=window)
mid = tk.Frame(master=window)
right = tk.Frame(master=window)

left.grid(row=0, column=1)
mid.grid(row=0, column=2)
right.grid(row=0, column=3)

## left
### Box1
box1_frame = tk.Frame(master=left)
box1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

#### Label
box1_label = tk.Label(master=box1_frame, text="Box1")
box1_label.pack()

#### Text
box1_text = tk.Text(master=box1_frame, width=20, height=10)
box1_text.pack()

### Box2
box2_frame = tk.Frame(master=left)
box2_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

#### Label
box2_label = tk.Label(master=box2_frame, text="Box2")
box2_label.pack()

#### Text
box2_text = tk.Text(master=box2_frame, width=20, height=10)
box2_text.pack()

### Box3
box3_frame = tk.Frame(master=left)
box3_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

#### Label
box3_label = tk.Label(master=box3_frame, text="Box3")
box3_label.pack()

#### Text
box3_text = tk.Text(master=box3_frame, width=20, height=10)
box3_text.pack()

### Box4
box4_frame = tk.Frame(master=left)
box4_frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

#### Label
box4_label = tk.Label(master=box4_frame, text="Box4")
box4_label.pack()

#### Text
box4_text = tk.Text(master=box4_frame, width=20, height=10)
box4_text.pack()

## Mid
### Buttons
button_frame = tk.Frame(master=mid)
button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        tk.Button(mid, text="Ironman", borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c, padx=12, pady=4)

some_frame = tk.Frame(master=mid)
some_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        tk.Button(mid, text="Taco", borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c, padx=12, pady=4)

#####################################################################################################
# Functions

# Start main loop
window.mainloop()
```

**Edit 1:**

I changed it to the correct parent view for the individual buttons and still obtain the ***SAME*** output. Nothing has changed.

### Mid

#### Buttons

```
button_frame = tk.Frame(master=mid)
button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        tk.Button(button_frame, text="Ironman", borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c, padx=12, pady=4)

some_frame = tk.Frame(master=mid)
some_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        tk.Button(some_frame, text="Taco", borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=c, padx=12, pady=4)
```

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: You have created `button_frame` and `some_frame` as children of `mid` - but then don't do anything with them.  Instead, you put all the Buttons directly into `mid`, using the same row/column numbers for both sets of them so they end up overlapping.

Comment: You're a beautiful human being and I'm a dummy.

Comment: If you can answer #1 as well, you can create the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @jasonharper added **Edit 1**